# Issue with BufferedInputStream getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, android

Below is the stack trace.

```
07-18 18:57:24.687: W/System.err(7031): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:675) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:659) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271) 
07-18 18:57:24.773: W/System.err(7031): at com.Webservice.downloadFileAddPassword(Webservice.java:192) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at com.patientcontext.DocumentViewerActivity2$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:219) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at com.patientcontext.DocumentViewerActivity2$DocumentsShowAsyncTask.doInBackground(DocumentViewerActivity2.java:1) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
07-18 18:57:24.777: W/System.err(7031): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
07-18 18:57:24.781: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
07-18 18:57:24.785: W/System.err(7031): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
07-18 18:57:24.785: W/System.err(7031): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am getting error in line 192 over these lines.

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileData));
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream(), 8192);
```

How to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);

You set a read timeout of 10 seconds.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

The read timed out.

Either your timeout is too short, or it isn't too short and you detected the condition you were trying to detect when you set the timeout.